# WSARecv doesn't stop reading

Tags: windows, sockets, go

So basically, I use WSARecv with this function from my client :

```
type Conn struct {
    sd s.Handle
    sa s.SockaddrInet4
}

func (c *Conn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    dataBuf := s.WSABuf{Len: uint32(len(b)), Buf: &b[0]}
    flags := uint32(0)
    qty := uint32(0)
    err := s.WSARecv(c.sd, &dataBuf, 1, &qty, &flags, nil, nil)
    return int(qty), err
}
```

Meanwhile the server is sending multiple packets (first one is 8 bytes, then they're all under 1000 bytes).

What happens is that WSARecv doesn't stop to read when the buffer `b` is full. So I got an hard answer when It's taking too much memory :

> Exception 0xc0000005 0x8 0xc08203195f 0xc08203195f
>   PC=0xc08203195f
>   syscall.Syscall9(0x7ff86cafe230, 0x7, 0x1f8, 0xc08200b5d0, 0x1, 0xc08200b5f0, 0xc08200b5e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
>   (dozen of lines like that)

And my program crash of course.

I wondered if my problem was about the way I use WSARecv or if I've to send back an aknowledgment every time I receive a packet.

NB : my server is under linux (and client under windows ofc).

Comment: You're passing in a buffer and len, so this probably isn't where you're running our of memory. This work is already done for you in the std lib. Unless you need some very specific socket handling, you should be using the "net" package. I would read through `fd_windows.go` very carefully to see how windows sockets are handled in Go.

Comment: It's a learning experience, so can't use "net" package. Between I'll take a look on `fd_windows.go`.

Comment: @kindermoumoute if you're still stuck, could you add more code on how you are initializing everything client side? and maybe a little on how you are sending the data from the server side too?

Comment: It's a bit messy but here is the whole project : [link](https://github.com/adrien3d/gobox)